# Get the value half way from line.new x1 and x2 and move a label to this value

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Im trying to add  a label to my line.new condition. But i dont want o just add a label.

I need the label to be at the midpoint of the line.new x1 and x2 location.

```
// Create Lines on Long Term Pivots
if not na(HiPivotyesno ? longhiPivothi : na)
    // Create a new line for high pivots
line newlongtermLine = line.new(bar_index[longpivotLegsInput], longhiPivothi, bar_index, longhiPivothi, color = longhiPivotColorInput, style=longtermlineStyle)
    line.set_width(newlongtermLine, width=Lpivotlinewidth)
    line.delete(qDq(longhiPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newlongtermLine))

---------------------Then it goes on to use this inside the same 'if' statement---------------------

// Create a new label for high pivots at the midpoint
    pivot_high_Label := label.new(x=((x1 + x2) / 2), y=longhiPivothi, text="High Pivot", color = longhiPivotColorInput, textcolor=color.white, style = label.style_label_down)
    // Change the label to bar numbers, and move it 6 bars to the right
    label.delete(pivot_high_Label[qtyOfLabelsInput])`
```

just so you know the "qDq" is a custom code. So dont worry about that.

and i know the code for the label.new placement is wrong in the code below, but im in the middle of making attempts that are failing to give me what im looking for.
To find the middle of any two values you use the formula, midpoint = ((point1 + point 2) / 2)
but i cant get the "integer value" of x2
Each time i attempt this, i simply get  HALF of the pivot lookback value.
So if my pivot input integer is 10, this will place a label 5 bars right from the bar_index, of the newlongtermLine x1 value.

This isnt what im trying to do.

Im trying to find the time value of x1 and the time value of x2 and divide it by 2. Then pass that time value as a bar instance for the label to be placed.
This way as the 'line.new' keeps plotting on each new bar that closes, the line gets longer and the label will effectivly always update itself one bar space to the right on ever other bar until the line is crossed (mitigated)
When the line.new stops updating its right value, its not longer getting "longer" so the label, stays where it is. THis point would be the center of the entire lenght of the line.new.

Comment: If you have drawn the line, the you have the information of `x1` and `x2` and you shouldn't need to "find" it. Also, you should work with TIME only if you work with the EXACT times of your time frame. If you work on the `hourly` chart, and your calculation gives you a half-an-hour result, anything you draw to that time will be invisible as that time point does not exist on the chart. Use `bar_index` instead, as that might be klunky, however it will still draw something instead of nothing.

Comment: correct but its not working
You can see in this line
line newlongtermLine = line.new(bar_index[longpivotLegsInput], longhiPivothi, bar_index, longhiPivothi, color = longhiPivotColorInput, style=longtermlineStyle)"
 bar_index[longpivotLegsInput is x1
and bar_index of the x2
but again my question remains
How do i tell something to plot to the point between these two coordinates?
the second bar_index is updating as new bars close until the line is mitigated so just a simple integer or ta.valuewhen wont work.
it needs to calculate on each  bar close and pass the value to the text